# Derivative of the logit function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have plotted a logit function and its derivative. My first question is that how can I interpret the derivative graph of the logit function and second, why in logit function, the second derivative becomes the logit function itself?

[image: enter code here]

Comment: Does this question has anything to do with the software Mathematica? If not, it probably should be posted in math.SE.

Answer (score 3):

The second derivative of the logit function is not equal to itself. Look:
$$l(x)=\ln\bigg(\frac{x}{1-x}\bigg)$$
$$l(x)=\ln(x)-\ln(1-x)$$
Then differentiate:
$$l'(x)=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{1-x}$$
Then differentiate again:
$$l''(x)=-\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$$
The second derivative of the logit function is a completely different function.

Comment: I believe the last term on the last line has the wrong sign

Answer (score 1):

Since you appear to be using Mathematica

```
logf[x_, a_, b_] := Log[a*x/(1 - b*x)]

With[{a = 1},
 Plot3D[logf[x, a, b], {x, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1},
  ClippingStyle -> None,
  PlotPoints -> 100]]
```

[image]

The first derivative of `logf` with respect to `x` is

```
D[logf[x, a, b], x] // Simplify
```

[image]

Note that the first derivative is independent of `a`

```
Plot3D[1/(x - b*x^2), {x, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1},
 ClippingStyle -> None]
```

[image]

The second derivative of `logf` with respect to `x` is

```
D[logf[x, a, b], {x, 2}] // Simplify
```

[image]

```
Plot3D[(-1 + 2*b*x)/(x^2*(-1 + b*x)^2), {x, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1},
 ClippingStyle -> None,
 PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]